# PHP FTP ftp_nlist not working, returning boolean false

Tags: php, ftp

I have a little problem with this pice of code. The script connects, but it wont give me the   folders that are located in root ... i am missing something?

```
    $ftp_server = "ftp.something.com";
    $ftp_user = "user";
    $ftp_pass = "pass";

    // set up a connection or die
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

    // try to login
    if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) 
    {
        echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
    }

    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
    var_dump($contents);

    ftp_close($conn_id);  

    die;
```

It outputs

```
Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server;
```

and

```
boolean false
```

Why it won't list the files?

i could solve this very fast with

```
  file_exists("ftp//user:pass@host.com")
```

... but the easy part is not what im looking for, i would not learn anything

Comment: Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

Comment: changed to error_reporting(E_ALL); and still nothing

Comment: `It outputs

Connected as $ftp_user` It should never happen as it should output the actual value of $ftp_user!

Comment: belive me it outputs Connected as user@host.com

Comment: i could solve this very fast with file_exists("ftp//user:pass@host.com") ... but the easy part is not what im looking for, i would not learn anything

Answer (score 71):

`ftp_nlist()` returns `false` when an error occurs. I'm guessing you need to use passive transfer:

```
// after ftp_login(...)
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Generell, I'd recommend troubleshooting this by using a a CLI tool like `ftp` or a GUI-client like Filezilla. The log/output is very, very helpful.

HTH

Comment: so there is someware a log.log that should have an error writen, is that right?

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs and I haven't tried it. And I don't have any FTP server. :) Does it work?

Comment: Setting passive mode solved problem for me. Things like this must be documented!

Comment: Yes this is an interesting problem to solve. Is there a way to easily determine on a server-to-server basis if you need to use a "Passive Connection". Also what does a passive connection mean?

Answer (score 29):

Don't be panic. Its easy to solve. After `ftp_login()` just use the code given in the below.

```
ftp_set_option($ftp_conn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false); // set ftp option
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true); //make connection to passive mode
```

This code solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would also just suggest confirming who and where you are to make sure that permissions and the actual results you expect are true (a little sanity check once in a while is healthy).

```
    echo shell_exec('whoami')." is who i am </br>";
```

and after you connect as user then

```
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "</br>";
```

if you can do these things from command line as this user and list contents of the directory then you should be well on your way.

Comment: i solved this long time ago with a simple file_get_contents(URI USER PASS), but your idea is good, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me, adding the following above your connection works:

```
putenv('TMPDIR=/tmp/');
```